# How to use deploy specific .env in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, webpack, deployment, environment-variables

I have several environments that I build my Vuejs application to.  Each of those environments has a different API that I'd like to call.

My ideal scenario is that I have an .env file in the root of each of the servers I deploy to, so that when I deploy my build, the Vue app looks at the .env that is in it's environment specific location and pulls the relevant API path variables from inside of it.

This way, I can build the app once, and have it deployed on multiple servers and I don't need to make a specific build for each server.

I've tried using dotenv-webpack but it seems that the .env that's included in the build is just from whatever the value is when I create the build, and not fetched from any .env on the individual servers.

I've found that I can use axios to GET a js file from /static but this doesn't really seem like the cleanest approach.

Comment: Have you looked at the npm 'config' package?  It picks up config based on your NODE_ENV environement variable. https://www.npmjs.com/package/config

Comment: I think this article addresses what you are asking about: https://alligator.io/vuejs/working-with-environment-variables/

Comment: @Jayem163 Looks like this pulls those env variables into the build, therefore, for each environment I'm deploying to (more than 5), I'd need to create a new build for each.  What I want is 1 build, that can deploy to all my different servers and they have their own env that they can grab those variables from.